# image of analytic set needs not to be analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables

I was trying to understand that the image of analytic set needs not to be analytic.

The book provide a example that $\{|z|<1\}$ is analytic set and the map $\zeta \mapsto (\zeta^2-\zeta , \zeta^3 -\zeta)$ with image under this map, the point $(0,0)$ is not analytic.

I don't know how to prove it, I don't have a picture or intuition of the image of the open unit disc.

Comment: Perhaps link to the definition of "analytic set".  It has more than one meaning... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that ,I use the definition in the several complex variables, which defines to be for each $p\in A$ exist a neiborhood $U_p\subset X$ such that $U_p\cap A = U_p\cap Z(f_1,..,f_N)$ for holomorphic function $f_i$ defined on $U_p$